# Lint tool for web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Greetings all,

As someone new to ASP.Net, I have been modifying web.config files for web apps I use and frequently breaking the apps in the process. I'm wondering if there is some kind of "lint" tool for web.configs which will analyse and look for potential problems.  Perhaps this is infeasible given that each web.config is specific to its app, version of ASP.net etc, but I thought I would ask anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [ASPhere](http://www.asphere.cz/en/index.html). It's an editor for .config files. It'd be difficult to write a tool that searched out potential problems because, as you've identified, one site's problem could be another's feature, but it should help you stop breaking your apps just because you entered something in web.config that just doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful tool. The comparison function is helpful. I wish there was a lint-like tool for web.configs though.